# Transformation matrices and their derivation (if possible) for ICRS frame for reference to other frames

Tags: positional-astronomy, astrometry, spherical-astronomy

I am finishing up my thesis write up and one of the chapters in my thesis is on astronomical coordinate systems since in my analysis of data I have converted the available astrometry from the ICRS frame of reference to the below coordinate frames,

1. ICRS to Galactic frame of reference
2. ICRS to Galactocentric frame of reference
3. ICRS to LSR frame of reference

I have also converted my reference frame from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates as and when needed.

I have done all these transformations during my study using the `SkyCoord` class from `Astropy`. I am trying to get to the literature of these transformations and so far I have failed. Does anybody have any reference to the literature of these coordinate transformations from one frame to another.

Answer (score 0):

Coordinate transformations are a concept directly derived from algebra.

Basically any transformation $(x,y,z) = f(\alpha, \beta,\gamma)$ is a coordinate transformation, usually if it is a bijection. All the rest is expression of this function and immediately follows from how the coordinates are aligned to eachother. In your case I'd simply reference the documentation of astropy.